# gcc compiles with no error with no return type (even using -Wall)

Tags: c, gcc, return-value

I'm wondering why gcc doesn't display an error while compiling, even while using the -Wall option. Also tried the -std=c89 option.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Sorry if this post is a duplicate but couldn't find a case where this option is being used.

Thanks!

Comment: despite that return type of `main` must be an `int`, the return statement of `main` and only `main` can be opted out, `return 0;` is implied

Comment: `main` is special, and you don't need a return statement in it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ and C99 and later, hitting the end of `main()` without returning a value is equivalent to returning 0. In earlier versions of the C standard it's undefined behavior which the compiler isn't obliged to issue a diagnostic for, although in practice GCC's likely doing an implicit `return 0;` just as it would for C++ or C99 onwards.

See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) for a lot more detail.

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 1K.